# Is there a way inside Sharepoint 2013 + Workflow 2010 to check if the "Workflow Context:Current User" belong to a sharepoint gorup

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, development, designer-workflow

I am working on sharepoint server 2013 enterprise. and inside sharepoint designer 2013 & workflow 2010, i am trying to implement the following senario:-

1. I got a list workflow that get fired when an item is created.
2. I want to check if the user who created the item (which is the same as `WorkflowContext:current User`) belong to a sharepoint security group, If so to set a site column named Team to be equal = CM
3. and if the user does not belong to set the Team= IT.

here is my list workflow:-
[image]

I thought that the above will might work in a way or another but it did not. so can anyone adivce on this please?

i also tried using "created by" as follow, but did not work either:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately , In SharePoint workflow platform 2013 and 2010, there is no OOTB action to check if the user belongs to a specific group.

Meanwhile, You can do this

- In SharePoint workflow 2013 via [REST](http://johnliu.net/blog/2014/12/15/spd2013-workflow-how-to-check-user-is-member-of-group.html) or via loop as a workaround.
- But Unfortunately , in SharePoint Workflow 2010 you only can build your own custom workflow activities.

**Note :** Don't try to check this solution http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/ I am pretty sure it's not working for SharePoint 2013.

**My suggestion :** No need for workflow at this section , try to build Event Receiver to update directly your team column based on the group of the current user as the following

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){
         using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
            {
             using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(properties.Web.ID))
               {

                  SPUser user = properties.Web.CurrentUser;
                   SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups[GroupName];

                                    if (!user.InGroup(group))
                                    {
                                        // update the list item
                                    }
                 }
                }
               }

  // ٍSEARCH USER WITHIN GROUP  
  public static bool InGroup(this SPUser User, string GroupName)
    {
        return User.Groups.Cast<SPGroup>().Any(g => g.Name.ToLower() == GroupName.ToLower());
    }
```

For more details about event receiver checks [What are the differences btw "properties.Web.CurrentUser;" & "web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);" inside my Event Receiver](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195722/what-are-the-differences-btw-properties-web-currentuser-web-users-getbyid)

Comment: thanks for lot for your reply. but can you please advice on these 2 points; 1) I found this link which allow to have the option inside designer workflow to check if a user exists inside SP group as mentioned here https://spdactivities.codeplex.com/ and seems it works with SP2013. 2) second point you mentioned to use a Event receiver, but as i did not write a event receiver before so can you please provide some general guide on what type of event receiver i need to create to achieve my requirement ?

Comment: Hi @johnG , regarding the first point , before I answered this question , I downloaded the package from http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/ because it's what you need and may help you , but unfortunately it's not worked for SharePoint 2013 , it requires WSS.30. also,  you can try this with yourself as a double check , but I am sure it's not worked ! ,  also the last version was released since 2008 . Regarding the Second point let me send to you step by step guide to can do this , and please tell me if you need more clarification

Comment: Dear @johnG , please check this link to know How to create Event Receiver Step by Step https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZf2xvEM5Io and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5b1f04/create-a-custom-list-level-event-receiver-for-item-added-in/ Please don't hesitate to tell me if you stopped at a any step

Comment: thanks a lot for the link. so mainly i will need to create a farm solution>>add new event receiver of type "List item events".. which fires when item was added.. now in my case i have 11 sub-sites, and each sub-site contain 4 issue tracking lists. so if i were to create this using sharepoint designer workflow, i will go to each sub-site and inside the related list will add the workflow..

Comment: but not sure how i can map this inside my event receiver, as on each sub-site i need to check for different SP group,, so i mainly need 11 event receiver,, and also i do not want the event receiver to fire on all the subsites lists,, i need it to fire on one list inside each sub site,, so where i can define these settings?

Comment: now i am not sure if InGroup(group) function is s built-in function .. as i can not reference it inside my event receiver?

Comment: ingroup is as example   I will update my answer with detail function body, I only mentioned this as suggestion because I don't know your requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46248/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-john-g).