# What are the differences btw "properties.Web.CurrentUser;" & "web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);" inside my Event Receiver

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, farm-solution

I added the following Event Receiver inside my sharepoint server 2013:-
1. Using VS >> add a new Event Receiver >> Type "List Item Events" >> when "item was created".
2. the idea of the event receiver is that i want to check if the user who created a list item , is within a specific user group or not? and set a site column named "Team" accordingly.
3. so i tried the following :-

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;
                        SPUser user = //properties.Web.CurrentUser; 
                          web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);
                        SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["CustomerA"];
                        foreach (var user2 in group.Users)
                        {
                            if (user2.ToString() == user.ToString())
                            {
                                currentItem["Team"] = "IT";
                                currentItem.Update();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
```

4. then i deploy the event receiver.

but the above did not wok as the site column value will not be updated. and when i debug the event receiver inside VS i got the following error "User can not be found" on `web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);`.
so i replace the `web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);` with this `SPUser user = properties.Web.CurrentUser;` and it worked well.

Q1) so can anyone adivce why i got an error on the first code (using "`Web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);`")?? while i did not get any error when using `properties.Web.CurrentUser;` ??are they the same ?

q2) second question. now i want to get the user who created the item? so which method i should use `properties.Web.CurrentUser;`  or `web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got  `"User can not be found"`  because the current user who adds the item does not have **explicitly** permission at the current list that means the current user not assigned to this list directly.

So in this case , you should use `web.SiteUsers` or  `properties.Web.CurrentUser` instead of `web.users`

Also, you should be aware of the difference between

- `web.SiteUsers` means get the collection of all users who belong to the site collection.
- `web.Users` means get the collection of users who explicitly assigned permission in the current web.

**are the `Web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);` and `properties.Web.CurrentUser;` the same ?**

Yes, the two statement should return the current user who adds the item . but the first one failed because the current user is not explicitly assigned permission in the current web.

`web.Users` output :

[image]

`web.SiteUsers` output :

[image]

`properties.Web.CurrentUser` output :

[image]

**now i want to get the user who created the item? so which method i should use properties.Web.CurrentUser; or web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId); ??**

the following statements have the same functionality , that it returns the current user **who Add the item**

`properties.Web.CurrentUser` **=** `web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);` **=** `web.SiteUsers.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);`

but to avoid any error related to explicit permission , you should use

`web.SiteUsers.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);` or `properties.Web.CurrentUser`

So the final code should look like

```
  public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
       //base.ItemAdded(properties);
      using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
       {
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            try
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                SPUser user = web.SiteUsers.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId);
                SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["EPM Sys Owner"];
                foreach (var user2 in group.Users)
                {
                    if (user2.ToString() == user.ToString())
                    {
                        properties.ListItem["Level"] = "IT";
                        properties.ListItem.Update();
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your great reply. but can you please explain what do you mean by explicit permission on the list ? now i have a site collection , which contain 11 sub sites , and each sub-site have 4 lists. and i am managing the permission at the site collection level , in other words when i created the subsite i chose to inherit the permission from their site collection.. so this mean my subsites does not have explicit permissions ?

Comment: yes you are right that what it mean , if you break inheritance and set explicitly permission for the user to  a list or web directly , so the user have explicitly permission

Comment: so in my case since i am inheriting the permission of the subsites from its site collection, then the web.Users.GetByID(properties.CurrentUserId); will always be empty ?